# {$x_n$} converges to $x$, {$y_n$} converges to $y$ and $|x_n-y_n|< \varepsilon$. Does x=y?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ converges to $x$ and $\left\{y_{n}\right\}$ converges to $y .$ If for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\left|x_{n}-y_{n}\right|<\varepsilon$ for all $n \geq M,$ then $x=y$

I am only a few chapters into an intro to real analysis course and this is a prove or disprove statement. I feel like it is true. We are saying the distance between terms in {$x_n$} and {$y_n$} is arbitrarily small, so surely they converge to the same thing? Maybe I am wrong though and I am not completely sure to go about proving this.

In order to show they are equal, I assume I have to show $x<y$ and $y<x$. I have tried to figure out what I know. Since {$x_n$} converges to $x$, we have that $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$ and since {$y_n$} converges to $y$, we have that $|y_n-y|<\varepsilon$. I could see the triangle inequality getting used somehow? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You're right, you'll have to use the triangle inequality.*

By the triangle inequality, for all $n$ we have
$$
|x-y| = |x-x_n+x_n-y_n+y_n-y| \leq |x_n-x| + |x_n-y_n|  + |y_n-y| \tag{1}
$$
Suppose now $x\neq y$, and let $\varepsilon_0 \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{|x-y|}{3} > 0$. Using your assumptions, there exists $M$ such that, for all $n\geq M$, 
$$
|x_n-x| < \varepsilon_0,\qquad  |x_n-y_n| < \varepsilon_0,\qquad  |y_n-y|< \varepsilon_0 \tag{2}
$$
*(can you see why?)*. Therefore, using (1) and (2) we get $$|x-y| < 3\varepsilon_0 = |x-y|$$ a contradiction.

Comment: For the can you see why, isn't it because we are given all of those limits, so they work for any epsilon we want to choose?

Comment: @Hmm this, and the fact that you can choose the same $M$ for all three (from the definitions and assumptions, you'll get $M_1,M_2,M_3$, but then can take $M = \max(M_1,M_2,M_3)$).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your intuition about the triangle inequality is good. Use the analysts' trick: add and subtract the same thing (hint:)
$$|x-y| = |x-x_n + x_n - y_n + y_n - y| \leq |x-x_n| + |x_n - y_n| + |y_n - y|$$
see if you can take it from here.

Comment: Dang, I always forget to use the "add an element and then subtract it back off" trick lol

Comment: My math teacher used to call that "Hiding zero." (Related: "hiding one" when writing $1=\frac{a}{a}$.)